# Timely tags on the bulletin board

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, community-bulletin-board

Inspired by [the ideas presented at "A way to bring attention to timely questions?"](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/288) and by [the new existence of the "Community Bulletin" board](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130892), I've taken the liberty of combining the two ideas: specifically, of linking to [lag-ba-omer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag-ba-omer)-tagged questions on our bulletin board. This is a temporary measure: that link went up on that board a few minutes ago and will remain there until approximately the end of *lag baomer* (in the western hemisphere).

[image: screenshot]

- Did you notice that link (before reading this post)?
- Do you think that that's a good/reasonable use of the bulletin board? Would you like to see other timely tags linked to in that way? Would you like *not* to?

Comment: I did noticed that link before reading this meta. I think it's a good idea.

Comment: Followup: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1409

Answer (score 4):

1) I didn't, but that's at least partly because I happened to already have Meta but not Main open on my browser, and I get notifications of new Meta posts.

2) I think that this is a great idea, and an elegant use of this new tool to fulfill [this idea](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288/a-way-to-bring-attention-to-timely-questions). We should do this for holidays, perhaps even 30 days ahead for major holidays. We may even want to do this for the weekly parasha, at least where we have a tag for it.

On the other hand, we should probably not maintain more than one or at most two of these at a time, since there are only four slots in the community calendar box, and we probably wouldn't want to routinely squeeze out the other items that can appear there. Perhaps the thing to do would be to formalize on maintaining one "featured seasonal tag" at all times, and filling that slot with holidays or parshiyot depending on the season.

Answer (score 2):

1) I didn't but that's only because you told me about it before you put it up. Under normal circumstances, I would have seen it on the board, as I glance at that regularly.

2) A wonderful idea! I believe that this is what the community board should be used for: meta links that the community should know about, and current community events (e.g. timely question tags).

I think this might be a great time to restart the weekly topic challenge!