# Weekly topic challenge 5772-04 (week of Vayera 5772): Shabbat songs

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

**This week's topic challenge is [*Shabas* (sabbath) songs](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat-songs). You're encouraged to think of and [post good questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this topic.**

#### What is it?

There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on. The topic is set each Wednesday or so.

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.

#### Who came up with this week's topic?

[Isaac Moses did.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441/weekly-topic-challenge-call-for-proposals/442#442)

#### How do we decide on *next* week's topic?

See [the call for topic proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441).

Comment: In the spirit of shabbat songs, can I suggest everyone who has a unique family tune record it for posterity here http://www.zemirotdatabase.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions that were posted on the occasion of this challenge:

1. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11173/shabbos-songs-why-are-some-popular-and-some-less-popular
2. [Who distributed the zemiros across the three meals?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11174/who-distributed-the-zemiros-across-the-three-meals)
3. [Koh Ribon - what connection does it have to Shabbos?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11175/koh-ribon-what-connection-does-it-have-to-shabbos)
4. [Parts of Shabbos prayers sung out loud](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11176/parts-of-shabbos-davening-sung-out-loud)
5. [Shalosh Seudos song - B'Vo'o M'Edom/Yetzave Tzur Chasdo](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11177/shalosh-seudos-song-bvoo-medom-yetzave-tzur-chasdo)
6. [Asking From Angels Borchuni Lshalom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11186/asking-from-angels-borchuni-lshalom)
7. [Go in Peace - why are we sending the Angels away](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11187/go-in-peace-why-are-we-sending-the-angels-away)
8. [Aishes Chayil talking about the Torah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11188/aishes-chayil-talking-about-the-torah)
9. [Aishes Chayil double talk](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11190/aises-chayil-double-talk)
10. [Zmirot vs Pizmoniim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11195/zmirot-vs-pizmoniim)
11. [כל מקדש שביעי כראוי לו and כל שומר שבת כדת why are we saying the same thing twice](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11213/and-why-are-we-saying-the-same-thing-twic)
12. [שכרו הרבה מאד or is it על פי פעלו](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11214/or-is-it)
13. [Why the Children of Avraham and not Yitzchok and Yacckov?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11216/why-the-children-of-avraham-and-not-yitzchok-and-yacckov)
14. [Why say Hashem is Jealous and Vengeful when we ask for Kindness?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11217/why-say-hashem-is-jealous-and-vengeful-when-we-ask-for-kindness)
15. [שָׁמְרוּ and לַעֲשׂוֹת whats the diffrence](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11219/and-whats-the-diffrence)
16. [What is וְשָׁם referring to in יוֹם שַׁבָּתוֹן?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11220/what-is-referring-to-in)
17. [Shabbos is Engraved in the two Luchos - I thought only one?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11221/shabbos-is-engraved-in-the-two-luchos-i-thought-only-one)
18. ["They answered Hashem is one." Where was that?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11222/they-answered-hashem-is-one-where-was-that)
19. [What is חית ראמים?‎](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11248)
20. [is there a good source for critical study of shabbat zemirot?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11252)
21. [Is repeating the chorus in Lecha Dodi problematic?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11257/is-repeating-the-chorus-in-lecha-dodi-problematic)
22. [Who is the object in Lecha Dodi?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11259/who-is-the-object-in-lecha-dodi)
23. [יִבָּנֶה הַמִּקְדָּשׁ עִיר צִיּוֹן תְּמַלֵּא — why not תִּמָּלֵא?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11271)