# Weekly topic challenge 5772-05 (week of Chaye Sara 5772): Navi: books of the prophets

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

**This week's topic challenge is *Navi: books of the prophets*. You're encouraged to think of and [post good questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this topic.**

#### What is it?

There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on. The topic is set each Wednesday or so.

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.

#### Who came up with this week's topic?

[Simchashatorah did.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/465)

#### How do we decide on *next* week's topic?

See [the call for topic proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441).

Comment: Does this mean questions arising in the books, such as [this one](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11196/why-did-gechazi-go-first), or questions about the books themselves, such as [this one](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7373/order-of-the-tanach), or both are acceptable?

Comment: @jake: Any good question on either topic is very welcome, anyway. As to whether it "counts" toward the week's challenge... sure, let's say both. Why not. (The nomination isn't clear on the issue.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New questions in answer to the topic challenge:

3. [Why were the prophecies of Eliyahu and Elisha not written as separate books?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11337)
4. [When did David Hamelech become king?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11338)
5. [Haftara reading customs](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11340)
6. [Navi will be annulled when Moshiach comes?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11351)
7. [All of Navi is in the Torah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11353)
8. [איש אחד What does the Echad refer to and where else in the Tanch is it found?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11371)
9. [Was Rachav really just a shopkeeper?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11379)
10. [Was King David also a Navi?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11381)
11. [בָּא אֵלַי הַפָּלִיט מִירוּשָׁלַ‍ִם ... How late was he?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11391)
12. [What are the "blind and the lame" that David wanted to be rid of when he entered Jerusalem, and what does that mean?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11395)
13. [Why was Shlomo more worthy to build the Beis Hamikdash than David?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11396)
14. [Should retroactive divorce (a la David & Batsheva) be reinstituted?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11459)
15. [The spelling of Eliyahu's name](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11479)
16. [Nothing new under the sun, except for women chasing men?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11490)
17. [Where else is Hashem's name missing?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11495)
18. [Why did Yonah run away?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11510/472)
19. [Why did Yonatan arrange the secret arrow sign with David?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11539)
20. [How and when does a prophet know that it's God who's speaking to him?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11546)