# Weekly topic challenge 5772-06 (week of Tol'dos 5772): Ribbis: loans at interest

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

**This week's topic challenge is [*Ribbis: loans at interest*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lending-interest-ribbis). You're encouraged to think of and [post good questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this topic.**

#### What is it?

There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on. The topic is set each Wednesday or so.

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.

#### Who came up with this week's topic?

[Alex did.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/468)

#### How do we decide on *next* week's topic?

See [the call for topic proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions on this topic added during its week:

- [How is a heter iska made to work with a non-business loan?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11554)
- [Are magazine subscriptions ribbis?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11572)
- [If magazine subscriptions are ribbis, are bus tokens, postage stamps, and other pay-in-advance items also ribbis?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11657)
- [Why is this not a valid way of evading the prohibition of ribbis?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11666)