# Weekly topic challenge 5772-07 (week of Vayetze 5772): Shidduchim: finding a spouse

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

**This week's topic challenge is [*shidduchim: finding a spouse*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shidduchim-dating). You're encouraged to think of and [post good questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this topic.**

#### What is it?

There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on. The topic is set each Wednesday or so.

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.

#### Who came up with this week's topic?

[Isaac Moses did.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/478)

#### How do we decide on *next* week's topic?

See [the call for topic proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New questions on the weekly topic posted during its week:

1. [Which authorities approve/disapprove of mixed events for singles?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11913)
2. [Genetic testing before the first date?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11922)
3. [Does someone who dies very young have  a soulmate?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11943)
4. [Can someone have more than one potential soulmate simultaneously?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11953)
5. [Was Rabbi Akiva obligated to divulge that his daughter was destined to die on her wedding day?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11968)