# Weekly topic challenge 5772-08 (week of Vayishlach 5772): Asked by children

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

**This week's theme challenge is *asked by children*. You're encouraged to think of and [post good questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this theme.**

#### Could whoever proposed this theme elaborate a bit?

[He did!](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/458)

> Children frequently ask questions, and at least some of the time, adults don't immediately know [all] the answers and have to either look them up or just give up ([e.g.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/485)). This challenge topic could spur people to notice when they hear children asking interesting questions or prompting interesting discussions, and could also spur people to recall questions they had when they were children.

#### What is it?

There's a single theme that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on. The theme is set each Wednesday or so.

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting them.

#### How do we decide on *next* week's theme?

See [the call for theme proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441).

Comment: Who voted to close??

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I don't, of course, know, but the reason given was "too localized: This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet", which is true (the "moment in time" bit).

Comment: OK, but meta's different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions posted on this theme during its week:

1. [Shmuel running and walking](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12083)
2. [Description of what Yaakov's sons plundered from Shechem](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12120)
3. [How does one explain God to little kids?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12128)
4. [Did hardening Paro's heart mean he wasn't really responsible?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12200)