# How does a question get bumped with no visible change?

Tags: discussion, recent-activity, community-user

[This question](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/515/472) is currently showing as last edited 2 days ago by "Community", but the last edits are from mid-December.  I have enough rep to see deleted entries, so it's not that.  This question is not the only time I've seen "mystery bumps"; I think I saw one on the main site on Friday (also "Community") but didn't have time to ask then and now I've lost track of it.

What can cause a post to be bumped without a visible reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a question doesn't have any upvoted answers for a certain amount of time, the Community user bumps it to the top for new attention.

Comment: Oh, neat!  That sounds like a good idea (I assume it only applies to questions where an answer hasn't been accepted).

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't apply to you, but for posterity I'll wrote this up.

The Community user "owns" edits made by now defunct user accounts. So, theoretical case for low-rep users:

1) User answers a question or edits a post.
2) User gets banned.
3) The post he modified/created gets deleted.
4) Tada! The question shows up as having been edited by Community, but the post has been deleted and so is invisible to low-rep users.

If you think this is "a bissel farfetched", it actually just happened on the "Do gentiles have neshamot" question with "jew slayer".