# Weekly topic challenge 5772-09 (week of Vayeshev 5772): Chanukah

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

**This week's topic challenge is *[Chanukah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chanuka)*. You're encouraged to think of and [post good questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this topic.**

#### What is it?

There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on. The topic is set each Wednesday or so.

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.

#### Who thought of this week's topic, anyway?

[Menachem did.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/529)

#### How do we decide on *next* week's topic?

See [the call for topic proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441).

#### I didn't know about this week's topic challenge! Why wasn't it advertised?

I used to advertise the weekly challenge in a message that appeared atop each page on [the main site](http://judaism.stackexchange.com). I was recently advised by Stack Exchange people that this challenge is really not the sort of thing that that spot is for. So it won't being advertised there any longer.

#### But— but— then how do I know when a new challenge is posted?

- Check back on [the meta site](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/) from time to time, especially on Wednesday or Thursday, to see if there's a new challenge post.

  - Check the meta site's [weekly-topic-challenge](/questions/tagged/weekly-topic-challenge) tag to see only the posts in the challenge, or its [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag to see all meta posts announcing currently-relevant site features and events.
- If you use a blog reader or otherwise follow RSS feeds, you can add the feeds for [`weekly-topic-challenge`](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=weekly-topic-challenge&sort=newest) or [`featured`](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=featured&sort=newest) to your reader and automatically get updates soon after they're posted. It might be a good idea to subscribe to `featured` anyway, to keep abreast of featured posts on the meta site.

Comment: *A comment by [Monica Cellio](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/users/472) that I accidentally deleted read:* We can also improve awareness of each week's challenge by linking in the earliest questions each week (either in the question or in a comment to it). It's a more gentle reminder than the banner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New questions on this topic during its week:

1. [Which Talmudic source for Ḥanukah is the real source?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12275)
2. [How are Spartans the son of Abraham?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12310)
3. [Fighting Wars on Shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12311)
4. [Origin of lighting the chanukiah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12353)
5. [Eating out Friday night of Chanukkah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12377)
6. [Joseph and Chanukkah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12379)
7. [What is the story of Yehudit which takes place during the Chanukkah Story?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12380)
8. [Pronunciation of חשמונאי](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12401)
9. [Which night of Chanuka should you give out Chanuka Gelt?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12422)
10. [Were the Books of Maccabees found in the Dead Sea Scrolls?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12427)
11. [Nice clothes for Hanukkah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12434)
12. [Rambam versus Ramban on Maccabees' taking the kingship from Yehuda](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12439)
13. [Marriv before/after lighting the Menorah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12441)
14. [Eating meat on Hannuka?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12449)
15. [Rambam placement of Hilchos Megilla vaChanukah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12459)
16. [Yochanan Kohain Gadol](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12464)
17. [Lighting the menora in shul and at home. How many brochos need be said?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12482)
18. [What is the meaning of the words כהיום הזה in the prayer על הניסים ?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12483)