# Can you design a Community Promotion Ad for the Weekly Topic Challenge?

Tags: discussion, weekly-topic-challenge, design, advertising

As reported [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/567), we have, for a limited time, the ability to create [Community Promotion Ads](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) to help build awareness for some of our regular site promotions, and how well we utilize this new tool is going to be watched closely.

So, I'd like to get a head start on ads for the features that we had in mind when we asked for this tool.

Can you design an ad for the [Weekly Topic Challenge](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441/weekly-topic-challenge-call-for-proposals)? Assume that the ad has to be for the Weekly Topic Challenge in general, and not for any particular week's challenge.

[We have a meta post for actually posting the ads](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/567); let's use this post to bounce some ideas around at various levels of development. As shown on the [official ads post](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/567), an ad consists of:

- An image file that's 220 x 250 pixels
- A tagline to show when someone mouses over the ad
- A URL to send a person to who clicks on the ad (presumably either [Weekly topic challenge: call for proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441/weekly-topic-challenge-call-for-proposals) or [a link to the current challenge](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weekly-topic-challenge+featured), in this case).

What should be in the image?

What should the tagline be?

Which URL should it go to?

Please post anything from fragmentary concepts to polished graphics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concept:

One-month calendar grid, with different one-word topics written across entire weeks.

Caption at the bottom: Jog your curiosity: A new challenge every week. Click for details.

Link is to [weekly-topic-challenge](/questions/tagged/weekly-topic-challenge).

Mouseover is the same as the caption.

Comment: workin on it ^_^

Comment: @Naftali, thanks! I'm looking forward to whatever you come up with.

Comment: See here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2827541#2827541

Comment: And posted: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/612/719 :-D

Answer (score 2):

(Revised based on comments.)

The URL will need to be persistent; we can't vary it each week because of the way the ads are set up.  All of the weekly-challenge pages on meta share a tag, so the URL could reasonably be for that tag with entries sorted by time (most recent first).  This would require a tag wiki to explain what's going on, but we should probably do that anyway.

Comment: I like this idea for navigability. The only drawback I can see is that it ads yet another housekeeping step for the person running the challenge each time the topic changes. Of course, it may be possible to have different people responsible for maintaining different parts of the challenge infrastructure, to spread out the load. Not as user-friendly, but automatically maintained, would be a [link](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weekly-topic-challenge?sort=newest&pagesize=15) to the series' tag, sorted by newest.

Comment: Oh right, the series has a tag.  A tag has a tag wiki.  I think we can work with that.  (I didn't know you could sort by date via URL; that would be essential.)

Comment: A wiki, right. Good point. This tag wiki definitely needs writing.

Comment: Grr. It seems that we [can't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92219/proposing-tag-wiki-creation-does-not-work-on-meta-sites) edit tag wikis here in meta.

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/611/allow-editing-of-site-specific-tag-wikis-in-meta