# Allow editing of site-specific tag wikis in meta

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, editing, tag-wiki

As discussed [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/565/2), it would be quite useful for us to create a meaningful tag wiki for [weekly-topic-challenge](/questions/tagged/weekly-topic-challenge), but unfortunately, it seems that we actually [can't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92220/179) edit tag wikis here on Meta; tag wikis in our Meta are supposed to come exclusively from [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

This case in particular demonstrates two general problems with the fact that we can't edit tag wikis in our Meta:

1. Some of our tags in Meta refer specifically to features or characteristics here on our own site. There will never be a corresponding tag on MSO.
2. If we can't edit tag wikis in Meta, the following text on the wiki is very misleading:

   > There is no tag wiki for this tag … yet!
   >
   > Tag wikis help introduce newcomers to the tag. They contain an overview of the topic defined by the tag, along with guidelines on its usage.
   >
   > All registered users may propose new tag wikis.
   >
   > (Note that if you have less than 4000 reputation, your tag wiki will be peer reviewed before it is published.)
   >
   > {Button: "Create Tag Wiki"}

For any tag in meta that doesn't exist on MSO, we should be able to edit the wiki. For any that does, the UI should make it clear that this is an imported tag whose wiki cannot be edited locally.

(I'm tagging this both [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) due to concerns 1 and 2, respectively.)

Comment: Also the edit link just goes straight back to the tag link: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/111

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tag wikis (including those tags that do exist on MSO) on child metas can now be customized.  (:

Comment: Woohoo! Thanks!