# Weekly topic challenge 5772-11 (week of Vayigash 5772): Violence

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

**This week's topic challenge is *Violence*. You're encouraged to think of and [post good questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this topic.**

#### What is it?

There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on. The topic is set each Wednesday or so.

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.

#### Who thought of this week's topic, anyway?

[Isaac Moses did.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/459)

#### How do we decide on *next* week's topic?

See [the call for topic proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441).

#### How do I know when a new challenge is posted?

- Check back on [the meta site](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/) from time to time, especially on Wednesday or Thursday, to see if there's a new challenge post.

  - Check the meta site's [weekly-topic-challenge](/questions/tagged/weekly-topic-challenge) tag to see only the posts in the challenge, or its [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag to see all meta posts announcing currently-relevant site features and events.
- If you use a blog reader or otherwise follow RSS feeds, you can add the feeds for [`weekly-topic-challenge`](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=weekly-topic-challenge&sort=newest) or [`featured`](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=featured&sort=newest) to your reader and automatically get updates soon after they're posted. It might be a good idea to subscribe to `featured` anyway, to keep abreast of featured posts on the meta site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions on this topic posted during its week:

- [Asara Haruge Malchut (Ten Martyrs), why were 10 Rabbis killed?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12817)
- [Self-defense (in a case of one's capital, not a capital case)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12897)
- [Stealing from or causing damage to a third party to save life or limb](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12936/stealing-from-or-causing-damage-to-a-third-party-to-save-life-or-limb)
- [Using physical force to get past a passive blockader](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12939/using-physical-force-to-get-past-a-passive-blockader)