# Weekly topic challenge 5772-13 (week of Sh'mos 5772): Korbanot

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

**This week's topic challenge is [*Korbanot*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/korban/info). You're encouraged to think of and [post good questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this topic.**

#### What is it?

There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on. The topic is set each Wednesday or so.

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.

#### Who thought of this week's topic, anyway?

[Double AA did.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/651)

#### How do we decide on *next* week's topic?

See [the call for topic proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441).

#### How do I know when a new challenge is posted?

- Check back on [the meta site](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/) from time to time, especially on Wednesday or Thursday, to see if there's a new challenge post.

  - Check the meta site's [weekly-topic-challenge](/questions/tagged/weekly-topic-challenge) tag to see only the posts in the challenge, or its [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag to see all meta posts announcing currently-relevant site features and events.
- If you use a blog reader or otherwise follow RSS feeds, you can add the feeds for [`weekly-topic-challenge`](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=weekly-topic-challenge&sort=newest) or [`featured`](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=featured&sort=newest) to your reader and automatically get updates soon after they're posted. It might be a good idea to subscribe to `featured` anyway, to keep abreast of featured posts on the meta site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions on this topic posted during its week:

- [Can one bring a Korban nowadays?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13254/can-one-bring-a-korban-nowadays)
- [Dictionary of symbology in Kodshim and Taharot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13310/dictionary-of-symbology-in-kodshim-and-taharot)
- [Was it only the tamid whose head was near the altar, and face toward the hechal?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13370)