# Weekly topic challenge 5772-14 (week of Vaera 5772): Midrashim and Aggadot

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

**This week's topic challenge is *midrashim and aggadot*. You're encouraged to think of and [post good questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this topic.**

#### What is it?

There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on. The topic is set each Wednesday or so.

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.

#### Who thought of this week's topic, anyway?

[Jake did.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/517)

#### How do we decide on *next* week's topic?

See [the call for topic proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441).

#### How do I know when a new challenge is posted?

- Check back on [the meta site](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/) from time to time, especially on Wednesday or Thursday, to see if there's a new challenge post.

  - Check the meta site's [weekly-topic-challenge](/questions/tagged/weekly-topic-challenge) tag to see only the posts in the challenge, or its [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag to see all meta posts announcing currently-relevant site features and events.
- If you use a blog reader or otherwise follow RSS feeds, you can add the feeds for [`weekly-topic-challenge`](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=weekly-topic-challenge&sort=newest) or [`featured`](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=featured&sort=newest) to your reader and automatically get updates soon after they're posted. It might be a good idea to subscribe to `featured` anyway, to keep abreast of featured posts on the meta site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New questions on the weekly topic posted during its week:

- [Moshe and the Red-Hot Coals](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13453/moshe-and-the-red-hot-coals)
- [What does the angel Gavriel represent?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13569/what-does-the-angel-gavriel-represent)
- [Anyone who says these people sinned is mistaken. For real?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13594/anyone-who-says-these-people-sinned-is-mistaken-for-real)
- [How is "החודש הזה לכם" the first mitzva?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13595)
- [The Plague of Darkness](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13624)