# Weekly topic challenge 5772-15 (week of Bo 5772): Kishuf (Magic)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

**This week's topic challenge is *kishuf (magic)*. You're encouraged to think of and [post good questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this topic.**

#### What is it?

There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on. The topic is set each Wednesday or so.

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.

#### Who thought of this week's topic, anyway?

[HodofHod did.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/598)

#### How do we decide on *next* week's topic?

See [the call for topic proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441).

Comment: What happened to "who came up with this idea?"?

Comment: @HodofHod, it's been gone for a few weeks. IIRC the guy who came up with the idea edited that section out of one week's post and it hasn't been seen since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question on the topic posted in its week:

- [Why don't we see magic today?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13636)
- [Did the prophets practice magic?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13693)
- [Did the Rambam believe in magic?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13696)