# Weekly topic challenge 5772-16 (week of B'shalach 5772): Light

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

**This week's topic challenge is *light*. You're encouraged to think of and [post good questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this topic.**

#### What is it?

There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on. The topic is set each Wednesday or so.

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.

#### Who thought of this week's topic, anyway?

[Monica Cellio did.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/496)

#### How do we decide on *next* week's topic?

See [the call for topic proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441).

#### What is this section for?

The software won't let me post the question without it, as this question is too similar to existing questions (like last week's topic challenge).

Comment: Not `trees` for Tu Beshvat this Tuesday?

Comment: @DoubleAA, [nope](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/441/weekly-topic-challenge-call-for-proposals/496#comment1624_496).

Comment: Is the only metric votes?

Comment: @DoubleAA, no, but it has the highest [effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New questions on the weekly topic posted during its week:

- [Bootstrapping problem: havdalah ends shabbat (for one who didn't daven ma'ariv) but lighting the candle is melacha?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13922/bootstrapping-problem-havdalah-ends-shabbat-for-one-who-didnt-daven-maariv)
- [How does a blind person make havdalah if he has to benefit from the light?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13947/how-does-a-blind-person-make-havdalah-if-he-has-to-benefit-from-the-light)
- [How seriously do we take the finger-inspection in Havdala?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13941/how-seriously-do-we-take-the-finger-inspection-in-havdala)

Answer (score 1):

The [winning](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3303887#3303887) question this week was ["Bootstrapping problem"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13922)! Congratulations to its asker, [Monica Cellio](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/472)!