# Weekly topic challenge 5772-25 (week of Tzav 5772): Book division

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

**This week's topic challenge is *book division*. You're encouraged to think of and [post good questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this topic.**

#### Topic Proposal

> I propose **book division** as a topic. Questions about dividing books into sections, chapters, *parashiyos*, *aliyos*, verses, paragraphs, pages, etc. I suspect there can be many more good questions on this; here are some we have already:
>
> - [Does one do aliya-ending notes when reading Torah in private?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/738)
> - [Stops in the Sidrah Leyning - Rishon, Sheni etc](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11465)
> - [The beginning of Maftir in Krias HaTorah on Pesach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/618)
> - [Who divided the Tehillim into days?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9253)
> - [Seven aliyot for V'zot Habracha?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10776)
> - [Division of Mishnayos in Pirkei Avos / Meseches Avos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7692)
> - [Rambam placement of Hilchos Megilla vaChanukah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12459)

#### What is it?

There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on. The topic is set each Wednesday or so.

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.

#### How do we decide on *next* week's topic?

See [the call for topic proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441).

Comment: [Tumbleweed!](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/badges/40/tumbleweed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions on this topic asked during its week:

- [Why doesn't the second chapter of B'reishit begin at 2:4?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15446)
- [The order of Tehillim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15450)
- [Why does the second aliya of Vayeira start with the last verse of one topic and then change?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15454)
- [Are T're Asar split at all?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15457)
- https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15474 (closed)
- [Tehilim HaChida - in the order of the Aleph Bais](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15499)