# Weekly topic challenge 5772-24 (week of Vayikra 5772): colors

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

**This week's topic challenge is [colors](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/color/info). You're encouraged to think of and [post good questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this topic.**

#### Topic Proposal

> I propose **colors** as a topic. We have but fifteen questions currently tagged [color](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color), and I suspect that it's something about which people can think of many more good Jewish-life-and-learning questions.

#### What is it?

There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on. The topic is set each Wednesday or so.

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.

#### How do we decide on *next* week's topic?

See [the call for topic proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two topical questions were asked during its week:

- [What are the colors of the rainbow?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15345)
- [What color is Yarok?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15347)

Of these, the latter has won the weekly challenge! Congratulations to its asker, [Double AA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/759)!