# Weekly topic challenge 5772-17 (week of Yisro 5772): Trees

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

**This week's topic challenge is [trees](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trees). You're encouraged to think of and [post good questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this topic.**

#### Topic Proposal

> I propose **trees** as a topic, preferably to be used during the week leading up to or following [TU Bishvat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tu_Bishvat) (which happens to be this coming Wednesday).
>
> There are currently 12 questions in the [trees](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trees) tag.

#### What is it?

There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on. The topic is set each Wednesday or so.

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.

#### How do we decide on *next* week's topic?

See [the call for topic proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441).

Answer (score 2):

The [winning](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3303887#3303887) question this week was ["What would the beracha be on tree-leaves?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14171)! Congratulations to its asker, [Isaac Moses](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2)!

Answer (score 1):

New questions on this topic posted during its week:

- [What would the beracha be on tree-leaves?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14171/what-would-the-beracha-be-on-tree-leaves)
- [How long does soil need to last?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14193)
- [Is there a bracha for blooming non-fruit trees?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14273/472)