# Weekly topic challenge 5772-18 (week of Mishpatim 5772): Unusual Blessings

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

**This week's topic challenge is *unusual blessings*. You're encouraged to think of and [post good questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this topic.**

#### Topic Proposal

> I propose **Unusual Blessings** as a topic. Many people are unaware of many of the blessings that Chazal gave us to give praise to Hashem. As the gemara in Bava Kamma 30a says, "He who wants to become pious should study the laws of Blessings."
>
> The questions I'm thinking of are not "What is the blessing on seeing a destroyed House of Avodah Zarah?" but rather "Do the Pacific and Atlantic Oceans count as separate for the purposes of the 30 day break between sightings necessarily to warrant a new blessing?"
>
> I'm confident that if people look through the list of blessings they will find some detail they hadn't thought of before to ask about. This will help raise awareness of the different blessings available and should provide for interesting discussion.

#### What is it?

There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on. The topic is set each Wednesday or so.

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.

#### How do we decide on *next* week's topic?

See [the call for topic proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441).

Comment: Reader Beware: I'll be asking that 'oceans' question whenever this topic is selected, so prep your answers!

Answer (score 3):

New questions on the topic posted during its week:

- [7 Seas or The Great Ocean?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14355/759)
- [Beracha upon seeing a friend on a webcam](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14372/759)
- [Where can I get "Afarsimon" oil?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14427/759)
- [Sh'hecheyanu vs. M'chayeh haMeisim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14498/759)

Answer (score 1):

**Thanks and congratulations to [Double AA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa), asker of ["7 Seas or The Great Ocean?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14355), which won the weekly topic challenge this week!**

Comment: I must admit that's kind of a let down :( We all knew that question was coming.