# Weekly topic challenge 5772-19 (week of T'ruma 5772): Practical Kabbalah

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

**This week's topic challenge is [*Kabbalah Maasis*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/kabbalah-maasis/info). You're encouraged to think of and [post good questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this topic.**

#### Topic Proposal

> I propose Practical Kabbalah or "Kabbalah Maasis" as a topic.
>
> This refers to the use of the knowledge of Kabbalah and the inner workings of creation, as well as the names of G-d and their permutations, to perform things that defy the laws of nature. Famous examples include R' Yochanan and Resh Lakish creating cows and Rava, R' Eliyahu Baal Shem, and the Maharal creating golems. Other common applications are "Kameas" (or amulets) and healing the sick.
>
> <strike>Currently no tag and therefore no questions exist for this topic.</strike>
>   As pointed out to me by @msh210. there does already exist (at least ;-)) one such question, and I have since asked one myself.
>
> Score: [kabbalah-maasis](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kabbalah-maasis) = 2

#### What is it?

There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on. The topic is set each Wednesday or so.

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.

#### How do we decide on *next* week's topic?

See [the call for topic proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441).

Comment: forgive me, since I'm new at this, would that mean that to "answer" this I would post my suggestion for a kabbalah maasis question below?

Comment: @Moshe. No. This is an announcement that this week you should come up with good questions on this topic and post them on the main site. The only answer that will be posted to _this_ question will be a list of all the questions asked once the week is done. See [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/454/weekly-topic-challenge-5772-03-week-of-lech-lcha-5772-aliya-laaretz) for comparison.

Comment: thanks, will do.

Comment: Hod, can we get a tag wiki for kabbalah-maasis? Not everyone can come to this post to find the definition.

Comment: @DoubleAA Done. What do you think?

Comment: Looks good thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one and only question asked on this topic during its week (and therefore the challenge winner by default) is: [Performing miracles with Hashem's Name](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14720), asked by [Moshe](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1255). Thank you, Moshe!