# Weekly topic challenge 5772-21 (week of Ki Sisa 5772): Medieval Jewish History

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

**This week's topic challenge is *Medieval Jewish History*. You're encouraged to think of and [post good questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this topic.**

#### Topic Proposal

> I propose as a topic Medieval Jewish History. There was a lot that went on and many names we are familiar with (Maimonides, Rashie etc.) but I think many people's knowledge of the time period is lacking. Questions could either be about the average Jew's life at the time in some place or about a specific person/event. I recognize it's a little vague...
>
> (I suppose we could generalize this to all Jewish history if people think it's too narrow, but I think it is sufficient to draw out some interesting questions.) EDIT: It seems the community tends to agree with me, so Medieval Jewish History it is!

#### What is it?

There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on. The topic is set each Wednesday or so.

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.

#### How do we decide on *next* week's topic?

See [the call for topic proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441).

Comment: I think its important to keep Jewish history to historical eras. (Medieval, Classical, Iron age, Bronze age etc.) I think too many people are likely to confuse eras of history especially the further back in the past you go.

Comment: I think (specific period) history is much better than just plain history for driving questions.  The latter is too broad.

Answer (score 3):

The only question on this topic in its week was ["What was daily life like for Jewish women living in al-Andalus in the 10th/11th centuries?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15079), which thus wins the weekly challenge by default.