# Weekly topic challenge 5772-22-23 (week of Vayakhel-P'kude 5772): Pets

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

**This week's topic challenge is *Pets*. You're encouraged to think of and [post good questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this topic.**

#### Topic Proposal

> I propose **pets** as a weekly topic challenge. Pets present [a number of](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/974) [*halacha*-related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13051) [questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11304); specific aspects of (or circumstances that come with) pet ownership may present more. Then there are the [historical questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3044), the philosophical questions, etc.

#### What is it?

There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on. The topic is set each Wednesday or so.

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.

#### How do we decide on *next* week's topic?

See [the call for topic proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441).

Answer (score 1):

Two questions on this topic were posted during its week:

- [Hamster Food and Chometz](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15228)
- [What can I feed my elderly cat during Pesach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15229)

Of those, the latter has higher net votes on the question; congratulations, then, to [Monica Cellio](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/472), its asker, as winner of this challenge!