# Pets are animals too

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

In light of the current [Weekly Challenge](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/859/weekly-topic-challenge-5772-22-23-week-of-vayakhel-pkude-5772-pets), [two](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15229/759) [questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15228/759) have been asked so far about pets. These questions used a new tag, [pets](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pets). We already have a tag [animals](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animals). Why both? I think questions about pets should go into [animals](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animals). Anyone disagree?

Comment: Note: If the community agrees with this proposition, don't retag all [tag:pets] questions. Rather, a ♦ mod can merge the tags, which is much quicker/easier and doesn't bump the questions to the top of the recently-edited-questions list.

Comment: As one of the offenders: I first tagged my post "animals", then saw the other one and said "oh, we have 'pets'" so retagged, and only long after that noticed that these were the only two.  I have no objection to merging them.

Comment: @msh210 It seems the community is rather indifferent.

Comment: Four months later and I've only seen three questions tagged "pets", the original two and one new one today.  I proposed a synonym.

Comment: As this has a net vote score of 3, @MonicaCellio's answer agreeing has a net vote socre of 2, and IsaacMoses's answer disagreeing has a net vote score of 0, I'm merging the tags as proposed and tagging this question [meta-tag:status-completed].

Comment: This title made me think of this: http://minnesota.publicradio.org/display/web/2006/05/25/jonathan_balcombe/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "pets" is unnecessarily specialized and there aren't that many pet-related questions.  (We do have some others that are currently tagged "animals", by the way.)  I say merge pets into animals and create a synonym.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't pets a special case of animals with their own particular set of issues?

I think the question really is whether there are likely to be a substantial number of pet-specific questions, and whether anyone will ever want to click on a tag to find them all (without having to sift through all the other animal questions). I think the answer to both of these questions is "Yes."

Comment: I would only agree that they deserve to be separate if someone can demonstrate a nafka mina: somewhere pets applies but not animals. Otherwise are we tagging _every_ pets question with animals too?

Comment: Kind of like your answer here: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/580/759

Answer (score 0):

It was I who created "pets" tag. If you think it is overspecialization, feel free to merge it.