# Weekly topic challenge 5772-40: Pirkei Avot

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

**This week's topic challenge is [Pirkei Avot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/pirke-avot-ethicsof/info). You're encouraged to think of and [post good questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this topic.**

#### Topic Proposal

> I propose questions relating to [Pirkei Avot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirkei_Avot) as a topic.

#### What is it?

There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on. The topic is set each Sunday or so.

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.

#### How do we decide on *next* week's topic?

See [the call for topic proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions on this topic asked during the challenge period:

- https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17469/translation-of-avot-13
- [Why does the Mishna not follow its own advice?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17480/what-does-the-mishna-not-follow-its-own-advice)