# Weekly topic challenge 5772-41 (week of Pin'chas 5772): Rashi

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

**This week's topic challenge is [Rashi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/rashi/info). You're encouraged to think of and [post good questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this topic.**

#### Topic Proposal

> I propose questions relating to [Rashi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi) (e.g. himself, his commentaries, etc.) as a new idea for a weekly discussion topic on our site.

#### What is it?

There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on. The topic is set each Sunday or so.

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.

#### How do we decide on *next* week's topic?

See [the call for topic proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441).