# Weekly topic challenge 5772-42-43 (week of Matos-Mas'e 5772): grains

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

This week's topic challenge is **Grains**. You're encouraged to think of and [post good questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this topic.

#### Topic Proposal

> I propose **grains** (wheat, barley, etc.) as a weekly topic.
> These plants comes up often in Jewish life, such as
>
> - in *m'nachos*,
> - re *b'rachos* before/after eating,
> - on *Shabas Shira*, and
> - re *kil'ayim*.
>
> I'm thinking specifically about issues concerning
> individual grains, *not* things like
>
> - [How big was a traditional hamentash?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6276) or
> - [Lechem Mishlesh?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13933).

#### What is it?

There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on. The topic is set each Sunday or so.

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.

#### How do we decide on *next* week's topic?

See [the call for topic proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441).

Comment: Is quinoa a grain?

Comment: @AdamMosheh, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=quinoa

Comment: @msh210 Perhaps AdamMoshesh is asking if you mean grains like דגן or grains like [grains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grain).

Comment: @DoubleAA Whatever. I was thinking of _dagan_, but the other's fine too.

Comment: @msh210 It's your proposal. You decide (and then [edit] to clarify).

Comment: @MonicaCellio thanks for fixing my copy-paste error!

Comment: Did this get any questions?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't recall. The Data Explorer should be able to tell you.