# Weekly topic challenge 5772-03 (week of Lech-l'cha 5772): aliya laaretz

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

**This week's topic challenge is [*aliya laaretz*, moving to the land of Israel to live there](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliya-laaretz). You're encouraged to think of and [post good questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this topic.** It is relevant to the weekly Torah reading, in which *Avram* moved to what later became the land of Israel.

#### What is it?

There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on.

#### How does it work?

[The topic is chosen from among proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441) on Wednesday, and the challenge begins: thinking of and **posting good questions in the [main site](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) on that topic**.

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.

#### Who came up with this topic?

[avi did.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441/weekly-topic-challenge-call-for-proposals/444#444)

#### Who came up with this idea, anyway?

[Isaac Moses](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2) [did](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281).

#### How do we decide on *next* week's topic?

See [the call for topic proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441).

Comment: If anyone wants to spruce up the relevant tag's [/tags'] wikis, that would be a nice contribution to this challenge as well.

Comment: ...namely [tag:aliya-laaretz] (and [tag:eretz-yisrael] is relevant too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the only preexisting question directly on the topic is ["Becoming Bnei Eretz Yisroel"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7000) from April.

New questions this week on the weekly topic:

- [What are good resources to find jobs for those contemplating Aliya?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11066)
- [Is one allowed to conditionally make Aliyah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11067)
- [What justifications are there for not moving to Eretz Yisrael?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11071)
- [Non-Israeli pulpit rabbis who actively promote moving to Israel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11083)
- [Mitzvah of living in Eretz Yisrael](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11084)
- [Why did the scholars of Bavel live in Bavel and not Eretz Yisrael?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11096)
- [Is there a best time of year to make aliya?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11143/472)

Comment: Some of these I think may be mistagged: they're about _yishuv haaretz_ but not specifically about _aliya_. Should we have a separate tag for the former?

Comment: Which of the ones currently listed here do you think are not related to the act of moving to Israel?

Comment: @IsaacMoses, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11084, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11096, and (despite its title) http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11071 are about living in _EY_ as opposed to moving there.

Comment: I think that the two topics are very much intertwined, especially in our context. The [main Jewishly significant] point of moving to Israel is to live there, and a major implication of the imperative to live there is an imperative to move there. I think that practically speaking, we'd have very few questions that would be tagged one and not the other.